# How to create email button on Android?

Tags: android, email, android-button

I'm a beginner at Android programming. I want to create specific email button on my program. (For example email adress is info@abcde.tv). When I click email button, mail program should open. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting the No applications can perform this action error, 
simply create an email account using your emulator. 
Android can't send mail from a non-existing email account.